# How to correctly implement class inheritance, annotated as @QueryResult in java neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm using neo4j + spring data. To access the data I'm using interfaces, that extends `GraphRepository<E>`. For example

```
public interface EntryRepository extends GraphRepository<Entry> {

    @Query("start parent=node({0}), entry=node({1}) "
            + "match parent-[*1..2{removed:false}]->entry "
            + "return distinct entry")
    Entry findOne(Long parentId, Long entryId);
}
```

I'm trying to get data, that differs from my domain models. My custom models looks like that

```
@QueryResult
public class EntryBean {
    @ResultColumn("id")
    private Long id;
    @ResultColumn("name")
    private String name;
    @ResultColumn("content")
    private String content;
    ...
    //getters and setters
}

@QueryResult
public class BoardBean {
    @ResultColumn("id")
    private Long id;
    @ResultColumn("name")
    private String name;
    ...
    //getters and setters
}
```

Obviously, that it will be better to separate duplicate fields to Base class and inherit from it. So, i'm doing next steps

```
@QueryResult
public class BaseBean {
    @ResultColumn("id")
    private Long id;
    @ResultColumn("name")
    private String name;
    ...
}

@QueryResult
public class EntryBean extends BaseBean{
    @ResultColumn("content")
    private String content;
    ...
    //getters and setters
}
```

And I don't need BoardBean anymore. But when I'm trying run query

```
public interface EntryRepository extends GraphRepository<Entry> {
@Query("start user=node({0}), board=node({1}) "
            + "... "
            + "return id(entry) as id, entry.name as name, entry.content as content")
    List<EntryBean> getRelatedEntries(Long userId, Long boardId);
}
```

I get filled by data just fields that directly declared into `EntryBean` class (i. e. "content" field). 
So, How I can correctly implement the `@QueryResult` class hierarcy?

Comment: What version of Spring Data Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: And what happens to the other fields are those empty? It's probably a shortcoming of the implementation right now where it checks for fields & annotations.

Comment: Yes, all inherited fields are null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which has been present for almost two years (even in `2.3.5.RELEASE`!) in [the class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/3.3.0.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/conversion/EntityResultConverter.java#L101) in charge of converting annotated POJOs.

Indeed, it calls `getDeclaredFields` on the most concrete type thus skipping possibly inherited annotated fields.

Before [the issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/289) is fixed, my piece of advice would be to tolerate this superficial field duplication on your side and not relying on inheritance for now.

Comment: So, if i will use lower version, i can resolve hierarchy problem?

Comment: I don't think so, this has been around for almost 2 years.
Downgrading to a much older version will likely be the cause of many adaptations on your codebase (and probably exposure to bugs that are fixed now).

Comment: Thanks a lot!)) This question bothered me a few weeks))

Comment: @Rolf This is `2017`. has the problem been fixed yet ? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I think the problem has been resolved. That was my mistake :)